# How to select each splited string and group by with another members in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

How to select many split string and group by with another members in linq?

```
class LogData
{
  public string IndexPattern {get; set;}
  public string Version {get;set;}
  public string Type1 {get; set;}
  public string Type2 {get; set;}

  //here has a constructor of this class
}
```

I have a list of Log Data Which have a many log datum.
The index pattern is the set of log index which use the delimiter ",".

```
List<LogData> logList = new List<LogData>();
logList.add(new LogData("1,2,4", "Ver1", "pro" , "etc" ) );
logList.add(new LogData("1", "Ver2", "pro" , "etc" ) );
logList.add(new LogData("2", "Ver1", "pro" , "etc" ) );
logList.add(new LogData("1,2,4", "Ver1", "pro" , "etc" ) );
logList.add(new LogData("1,5", "Ver2", "pro" , "set" ) );
```

And i want split index patterns and group by all member like this.

```
[Index] [Version] [Type1] [Type2] [Count]
  1        Ver1     pro      etc    2
  2        Ver1     pro      etc    2
  4        Ver2     pro      etc    2
  1        Ver2     pro      etc    1
  1        Ver2     pro      set    1
  5        Ver2     pro      set    1
  4        Ver2     pro      set    1
```

And i write linq like this to group by first..

```
var LogGroup = HackingLogs.GroupBy(g => new {
              IndexPattern = g.IndexPattern.SelectMany( new { Index = c => c 
               }),  //I must select many to get each splited  string
                g.Version,
                g.Type1,
                g.Type2
 }); //I group by this for each splited string and all member pairs to select
```

But it can not group by. so i can not use select.
May i have some answer for this problem?

Comment: Combination which you showed in last row of table is not available in the declaration.

Comment: Your output in tabular format is misleading to viewers, please correct it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first flatten the `IndexPattern` using [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx) and project all other elements. Finally group by all columns and get the Count. 
This should give you the expected output:-

```
 var res = logList.SelectMany(x => x.IndexPattern.Split(',')
                                  .Select(z => new 
                                      { 
                                           Index = z, 
                                           Version = x.Version, 
                                           Type1 = x.Type1, 
                                           Type2 = x.Type2 
                                      }))
                   .GroupBy(x => new { x.Index, x.Version, x.Type1, x.Type2 })
                   .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Index = x.Key.Index,
                            Version = x.Key.Version,
                            Type1 = x.Key.Type1,
                            Type2 = x.Key.Type2,
                            Count = x.Count()
                        });
```

[Working Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tB5YcV)

Comment: Thanks for answering! May i have a question? I can't understand what  flatten IndexPattern meaning.

Comment: @summation - Just refer to the `SelectMany` MSDN link and read it's use. So here you have comma separated `IndexPattern` right if you imagine it as a flat list (means only 1-1 item in each object) you will have to split it like : {1, "Ver1", "pro" } , {2,"Ver1","pro" } and so on..

Comment: Magic of **linq** Kudos to your answer

Answer (score 1):

**Today I learnt magic of Linq**.
**Here is the code without using Linq**

I found this problem as interesting, so just posting my try.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public class LogData
    {
      public string IndexPattern {get; set;}
      public string Version {get;set;}
      public string Type1 {get; set;}
      public string Type2 {get; set;}

      //here has a constructor of LogData class
        public LogData(string indexPattern, string version, string type1, string type2){
            IndexPattern = indexPattern;
            Version = version;
            Type1 = type1;
            Type2 = type2;
        }
    }

    public class GridData
    {
      public string Index {get; set;}
      public string Version {get;set;}
      public string Type1 {get; set;}
      public string Type2 {get; set;}
        public int count {get;set;}

      //here has a constructor of GridData class
        public GridData(string indexPattern, string version, string type1, string type2, int count){
            Index = indexPattern;
            Version = version;
            Type1 = type1;
            Type2 = type2;
            this.count = count;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(){
        //Inputs
        List<LogData> logList = new List<LogData>();
        logList.Add(new LogData("1,2,4", "Ver1", "pro" , "etc" ) );
        logList.Add(new LogData("1", "Ver2", "pro" , "etc" ) );
        logList.Add(new LogData("2", "Ver1", "pro" , "etc" ) );
        logList.Add(new LogData("1,2,4", "Ver1", "pro" , "etc" ) );
        logList.Add(new LogData("1,5", "Ver2", "pro" , "set" ) );

        //Calculate the results
        Dictionary<string, GridData> result = GetResult(logList);

        Display(result);
    }

    //Read all data and Get result in tabular format
    public static Dictionary<string, GridData> GetResult(List<LogData> logList){

        //Initialization of local variable
        List<LogData> elements = new List<LogData>();
        Dictionary<string, GridData> output = new Dictionary<string, GridData>();

        //Iterate through each input
        foreach(LogData ld in logList){
            LogData temp = new LogData("", "", "", "");

            //Check for multiple Indexs in one list
            if(ld.IndexPattern.Contains(",")){
                string[] strArr = ld.IndexPattern.Split(',');

                //Consider each index as one record; Time complexity: O(n*m) very bad
                foreach(string s1 in strArr){
                    temp = new LogData(s1, ld.Version, ld.Type1, ld.Type2);
                    elements.Add(temp);
                }
            }
                //Else record as it is
            else{
                elements.Add(ld);
            }
        }
            //List elements contains all seperated records
            foreach(LogData logData in elements){
                //Create unique key by concatenating all properties into string
                string key = logData.IndexPattern + "_" +  logData.Version +"_"+ logData.Type1 +"_"+logData.Type2;

                //Increment counter if record is already exist
                if(output.ContainsKey(key))
                    output[key].count++;
                else{
                    //Insert new record
                    GridData gd = new GridData(logData.IndexPattern, logData.Version, logData.Type1, logData.Type2, 1);
                    output.Add(key, gd);
                }
    }
        return output;
    }

    //Display in tabular format
    public static void Display(Dictionary<string, GridData> output){
        foreach(string str in output.Keys){

            Console.WriteLine(output[str].Index +"\t"+ output[str].Version +"\t"+ output[str].Type1 +"\t"+ output[str].Type2 +"\t"+ output[str].count);
        }
    }
}
```

Improvements are appreciated. [DotNetFiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jGeqIC)